# Get params value from component Joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I have saved value like this in my component table fields params.

```
unique=1
default_value=Default
validate=Validate
validate_error_msg=Validate error messag
searchable=1
```

Now i want to get value in my component.So I am passing values in my component's view.html.php 
in this way 
`$params    = new JForm($row->params);` but its not working.
Now I want to get value so I am taking like this

```
$this->params->getValue('default_value');
```

But its not work where as in Joomla 2.5 ,we can get value like this

```
$this->params->get('default_value');
```

Comment: Above table fields are getting from `form xml` or component options(setting config.xml) file ?

Comment: I am saving this type of value in DB table field named params

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

For Ex.

```
$param  = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users');
$default = $param->get('default_value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use

```
$params->get('your_parameter_value_name');
```

instead of

```
$this->params->get('your_parameter_value_name');
```

It should work.